# Why doesn't my php code use checkbox info to iterate through my switch?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a website that uses php to render modules on the page. At the moment the only discerning that the site does in terms of what modules are shown are whether you are logged on or not.  If you are logged on, it shows them all, if not, only a select few.  What i've been attempting to do is allow the user to filter out modules using checkboxes, but my code isn't working.  I may be missing something simple, so was hoping a new set of eyes would uncover what i'm missing.  Here is what i have so far.

```
 <form >
      <input type="checkbox" name="Categories" value="Categories"> example1<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Categories1" value="Categories1">   example2<br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Categories']))
    {
        $variable = 1;
    }
    elseif (isset($_POST['Categories1']))
    {
        $variable = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "You haven't picked anything!";
    }
?>
<?php switch($variable): 
    case 1: ?>
        <div class="col-md-4 module" id="exampleID"> example1 </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 module" id="exampleID"> example2 </div>
    <?php break;?>
    <?php case 2: ?>
        <div class="col-md-4 module" id="exampleID"> example3 </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 module" id="exampleID"> example4 </div>
    <?php break;?>
    <?php default;?>
        <div class="col-md-4 module" id="exampleID"> example1 </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 module" id="exampleID"> example2 </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 module" id="exampleID"> example3 </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 module" id="exampleID"> example4 </div>
<?php endswitch;?>
```

The problem i'm getting is that its always showing everything.  Not just the 4 like it's supposed to, but the 4 plus all the ones inside the other cases as well. The desire that i'm looking for is, if I check the first box, then the page would display:

```
example1
example2
```

If I checked the second box:

```
example3
example4
```

If I didn't have any box checked:

```
example1
example2
example3
example4
```

Hoping you guys can help me out.

Edit -

This is the output i'm currently getting:

```
Example1
Example2
Example3
Example4
Example1
Example2
Example3
Example4
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you "post" the data via a form? Is that the complete HTML?

Comment: Oh, I've edited it for a different approach using the forms and added a submit button.  I knew I was missing something.  However, it still doesn't work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: `<form method="post">` This should help If you dont name a method it is get, not post

Comment: @Webice - you should post that as an answer, because it clearly is the cause of the problem.

Comment: So I added what you suggested, but I'm still running into the same problem.  The code is just displaying 8 outputs, i've added it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered:

Below is the code I finally came up with to do what I wanted. I'm also adding in the updated checkboxes. Hopefully this could help someone else.

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
                <!-- Sets All The Modules To Show By Default -->
                startup();

                $(".CategorySelector").click( function() {
                                //$(this).value

                                //Hide All Modules
                                $('div.module').each( function() {
                                            $(this).hide();                                     
                                })
                                var chooseCat = 0;
                                //Loop through category selectors and show modules
                                $("input.CategorySelector").each( function() {
                                                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                                                    chooseCat++;
                                                    showCategory($(this).val())
                                                } 

                                })      

                                if (chooseCat == 0){
                                    startup();
                                }
                })
});


function startup() {
                $('div.module').each( function() {
                                $(this).hide();                                     
                })                  
                $('div.module').each( function() {
                                $(this).show();
                })
}

function showCategory(Category) {
                var selector = '[categories~="'+Category+'"]';
                $(selector).each( function() {
                                $(this).show();
                })
}
</script>
```

Checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="CategorySelector" value="value1">
Example1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="CategorySelector" value="value2">
Example2<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="CategorySelector" value="value3">
Example3<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="CategorySelector" value="value4">
Example4<br>
```

One thing I did want to try and do is embed the checkboxes into an iframe and then create like a sliding tab so the navigation isnt intrusive. However, firstly, I have no idea how to call the data from an iframe. And secondly, I don't know how to do the sliding animation. Things to look forward to :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post">
```

This should help If you dont name a method it is get, not post.

And for better reading / clean code you should use echo in your switch statement.